# Display dicom in JavaFX button

Tags: java, image, javafx-2, dicom

I have many dicom (dcm) images that I want to display as thumbnails in my program. I can load it and draw in a separate window with ImageJ plugin:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dcms);
    DICOM d = new DICOM(fis);
    d.run(dcms);
    d.setTitle(title);
    d.show();
    d.draw();
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

}

But I want to be able to load it as a Image in a JavaFX button (as thumbnails) as I can do with pngs:

```
try{
    Image picture = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(dcms));
    bt.setGraphic(new ImageView(picture));
}
```

I couldn't find any similar example on Google (most of the results lead to programs to convert the dicom to another thing through a program). But I don't want to convert and then display, I just want to display it.

Do you know if it's possible? Or will I have to convert it before loading the thumbnails?

**EDIT :** I know that I can save each picture somewhere e.g temp folder and then load it as a Image, but I still think that it's a *unnecessary workaround*. And I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to use it:

```
            FileInputStream fis;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(path);
                DICOM d = new DICOM(fis);
                d.run(path);
                Image picture = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(d.getBufferedImage(), null);
                Button bt = new Button();
                bt.setGraphic(new ImageView(picture));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Posted because it might be useful for someone else.

Comment: Where DICOM class comes from? Is it prebuilt in JavaFX?

Comment: @IhsanHaikal as you can see in my question, it is from the ImageJ

Comment: It doesn't specify the ImageJ in the question but now I already found it. Thanks